# Should I use an array or a string to store letters

Tags: javascript

I've got a constant element where I only have letters.
I'll only need to output the requested letter by an index.

Here is a simple snippet to illustrate what I mean:

```js
// As array
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}

// As string
const str = "abcd";
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(str[i]);
}
```

Both ways seem to be working well.
So, I found myself wondering *“Hmm. Should I use an array or a string?”*.

What are the technical limitations that would give objective answers about this choice?

Comment: I think string is a better way.

Comment: If it's too long: Array. Otherwise, String is good.

Comment: I think that array is more natural in this case as you operate with separate items, which are not intended to be a one piece.
Moreover array has more built-in methods for managing the items like map, reduce, filter, etc.

Comment: I vote for an Array, it will be easier to maintain your code in Future

Answer (score 2):

**If** the letters are all represented with a single UTF-16 code unit (for instance, all English letters are), then it's entirely up to you whether to use an array with `[n]` or a string with `[n]` or `.charAt(n)`.

If the "letters" are not all represented with a single UTF-16 code unit (for instance, if they're really emojis), then you're better off with the array, since if you used a string, you'd have to use [`.codePointAt(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) (which is relatively new) and (confusingly!) you'd have to figure out what `n` to use (since `codePointAt(n)` **isn't** "give me the nth code point", it's "give me the code point at string index *n*" — e.g., `n` is still measured in code *units*, not code points. And then you'd have to run it through `String.fromCodePoint` to get the "letter" back.

(This is because [JavaScript strings](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) aren't strings of *characters*, they're strings of UTF-16 code units [tolerating invalid surrogate pairs]. Some characters [what Unicode calls "code points"] can't be represented with a single UTF-16 code unit, and a pair of them is required instead. For instance, `"".length` is `2` because that emoji requires two code units.)

If you're using a modern environment and want the simplicity of using a string literal to write the letters, but you need to handle the code point issue, you could create the array from the string like this:

```
const letters = [..."abcd"];
```

Strings are iterable in modern environments, and they iterate over code points, not code units.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified a bit my question, do you think it could be reopened?

Comment: @TakitIsy: I do indeed.